# Prevent Apache Velocity from escaping

Tags: html, escaping, velocity

My template goes like this

```html
<tr>
    <td style="white-space:normal">$claim.getClaimId()</td>
    <td style="white-space:normal">$claim.getStatus().getValue()</td>
    <td style="white-space:normal; text-align:left">
        $claim.getComment()
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now, when I try to build the template with the following string in the comment field "Today's weather forecast is", velocity ends up rendering it as

> [image: error]

How do I prevent it from escaping my characters?

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is format-agnostic. It won't escape HTML entities by itself, so this encoding is probably done by the `getComment()` method.

By the way, do you know that you could write `$claim.claimId`, `$claim.status.value` and `$claim.comment`, and let Velocity call the getters itself?

Comment: The getComment() method just returns a string. And I tried with the property addressing scheme as well. But I end up with the same problem.

Comment: Ah, then probably you have a reference insertion event handler in your velocity.properties file, a line like "eventhandler.referenceinsertion.class = org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.EscapeHtmlReference". You just have to remove it.

Comment: Nope. I just checked. Does having 
RuntimeConstants.INPUT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
RuntimeConstants.OUTPUT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
cause any problems?

Comment: No. They're fine. What happens if you do: `#set($foo='>') $foo`? Does it display > or &lt; ?

Comment: Interestingly, it prints >

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the HTML entities are not already present in the comment string?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. It's just a simple string, just like this comment.